# RDLC Report Hidden Charts Creates Empty Pages

Tags: reporting-services, charts, rdlc

I have multiple Charts in the RDLC Reports. I'm hiding and showing the Charts by expression using the Visibility option.

My problem is, the report creates multiple empty pages.

**Note:**

1. Margins are already set to Fit within the Paper size.
2. `'Consume Container WhiteSpace'` also set to `'False'`
3. Footer already stretched upto the bottom of chart line.

**Any Other Solutions Please!!**

Screen Shot - 1:

[image]

Screen Shot - 2

[image]

[Tried with These options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVMCz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a small textbox in the header and assign it the following expression

```
Globals!TotalPages
```

Hide the text box.. it will show how many pages you have in your preview screen.

Ensure you have `ConsumeContainerWhitespce` report property as True.

Ensure the report margins are wide enough so they don't run over two pages.. pull your chart width in a few mils at a time until you get it to fit on one page.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply!    1. Margins are already set to Fit within the Paper size.
 2. 'Consume Container WhiteSpace' are set to 'False'
 3. Footer already stretched upto the bottom of chart line.

Any Other Solutions Please!!

Comment: Set consumecontainerwhitepace to TRUE

Comment: Hi, I tried both the options TRUE and FALSE. Not solved.

Comment: 16 charts totally, but always one chart will be visible as per the condition selected... balance will be hidden by expression

Comment: Ok . In that case.. once you have finalised all your charts. Draw a rectangle the size of the biggest chart and then drag all your charts into that rectangle. It doesn't matter if they over lap each other. Set the rectangle to not grow. Give that a go.

Comment: Hi, Working fine. I just overlapped all the charts by keeping all the chart location in "Properties" as same... Thanks