# RDLC Report Hidden rectangles Creates Empty Pages

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I found a similar question on the link: [rdlc-report-hidden-charts-creates-empty-pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474147/rdlc-report-hidden-charts-creates-empty-pages), but it didn't helped.

I have two sections that needed to be hidden when data is not present. however after adding a new section in the accident info section I am getting the error. My page size is 8.27in, 11.69in. Interactive size is 8in, 11in.

On that section previous height was 7.8 inch now its increased to 8 inch. After subtracting header and footer 8.4 inch space is available for the page. if margin is considered only 0.1 inch margin is there for all sides. ConsumeContainerWhitespace is also true.

For some data where these two rectangles are not visible an empty page is generated. This should not be the case as after hiding them from expression widget moves up automatically. On some sections property "PageBreak" is set to BreakLocation=Start. It is because some sections needs to be saved in a new page.

page before break

[image]

Page after break

[image]

here is the sample code for RDLC

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
  <ConsumeContainerWhitespace>true</ConsumeContainerWhitespace>
  <rd:ReportUnitType>Inch</rd:ReportUnitType>
  <rd:ReportID>38832df4-093b-4332-b811-4e31095617ec</rd:ReportID>
</Report>
```

Sorry I am unable to load my full RDLC as the body limit is exceeded.
I am using reporting version 8.

Comment: Are all data presented using a Tablix? Is the property `CanStrink` set to `true` for the Textboxes?

Comment: @HardcoreGamer I tried with textbox property CanShrink to true, but it didn't helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I would like to thank @HardcoreGamer for support. In this case I tried with only Tablix widget with row visibility and widget visibility based on expression. None of the approach worked. I had got one concept wrong that on hiding the widget or Tablix report takes no space. The report takes space which is between the widgets.
I also tried with two different schema as well i.e. RDL 2008 and 2016 but same thing happened on both.
I posted similar question on Microsoft form as well : [RDLC Report Hidden rectangles Creates Empty Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/509426/rdlc-report-hidden-rectangles-creates-empty-pages.html)

What finally worked is that I reduced the rectangle of previous page by a margin of 1 inch excluding padding, page margin and footer for A4 size page. The space between the widgets was 0.5 inch. for hiding two widgets additional space of 1 inch is required, so that a new page doesn't gets generated.

[Final image with changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4djb1.png)

I still have to find a way out if data increases then the new page dosent get generated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may work if you move the content of the textbox inside a Tablix.

Then use `Row Visibility` to hide / show that row instead of the textbox itself.

[image]

[image]

If your design is more complex, like multiple combination of hide / show textbox.

You will need to use the `Show or hide based on an expression` function to check all textboxes' visibilities.

Comment: by tablix do you mean a table or matrix control. Presently my control is inside a rectangle and it is a List widget. I have kept hidden condition on rectangle.

Comment: @RajeevLohani I just checked. The List widget also has a row visibility setting that can Show or Hide row.

Comment: I tried with hidden condition on both outer rectangle and row visibility for inner list, still an empty page is generated. I think even by hiding the whole widget it seems that some space is taken by the hidden widget and it generates a blank page. Ideally if a widget is hidden the visible widget next to it take its place.

Comment: `Ideally if a widget is hidden the visible widget next to it take its place` Such function is not supported AFAIK. You need to have all data contained inside a List or Tablix. Then hide or show rows (section) depend on conditions. This way when the row is hidden, the next row (section) will automatically move up.

Comment: Thanks @HardcoreGamer I will try to redesign my report with only listbox or table instead of nested controls.